# Are there any additional advantages to use SLF4J library instead of Apache Log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I came across this library for logging [slf4j](http://slf4j.org) in my assignment. I have used apache [log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html) library before but from the documentation I could not understand the use case for the slf4j library. (face palm)
Can any one tell me the advantages of using SLF4j or possible real world cases.

Comment: I will remove my comment because they now polluate your question :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [SLF4J Website](http://slf4j.org/manual.html) (Bold annotations is something I made):

> The Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J) serves as a simple facade
>   or abstraction for various logging frameworks (e.g. java.util.logging,
>   logback, **log4j**) allowing the end user to plug in the desired logging
>   framework at deployment time.

Thus, it would seem that the SLF4J library provides an abstraction of the underlying logging framework used. This, as per their website, would allow you to write applications which are independent of the logging framework used since SLF4J wraps over the underlying logging mechanism. Thus, as far as your application would be concerned, it won't care what underlying logging mechanism you are using.

Comment: We see this during testing, where we use log4j. On our target we have to use a different logging module (provided by someone else). Because everybody uses slf4j we can use a different framework without changing a line of code.

Comment: @npinti But in my  case, I use always log4j and I do not change the logging mechanism at all in my application.

Comment: The main advantage is for library developers. Which logging framework should you use? SLF4J comes to rescue here as the choice can be left open to the application developer who uses the library.

Comment: But there is also an advantage for an application developer as you can easily move to another logging framework if required - eg. to the new Log4j 2 library. Often you don't have to change a single of code, just some configurations.

Comment: @rockyit86: In addition to what Puce mentioned, there are situations where you want to provide logging capabilities without tying yourself to a particular logger. This is usually the case for framework developers. People who use your framework might be used to a particular logging framework. What SLF4J provides is a way in the middle. It allows you to log without specifying a specific logger. It is up to whoever makes use of your framework to specify one.

Comment: @npinti Hey thanks man, this is what I exactly wanted, you opened my mind :)

Comment: For some one who are the beginners like read this link for more clarification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272054/migrating-a-project-from-log4j-to-slf4jlog4j?rq=1